# How to add comments in the android translation file

Tags: android

We find the comment messages are very helpful when we give the file to translators. For Android app, is there a way to add a comment message in the **strings.xml** for the translator?

```
// In the strings.xml
<string name="hello___">Hello %1$s</string>
```

On iOS, we can do this:

```
// In the code, when we export the translation file to xliff, 
// The comments in `NSLocalizedString` will be collected and inserted into the xliff file
NSString *greetingMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"hello__", 
      @"A simple greeting messsage, %@ will be replaced by user's name");

// In the Localizable.strings file
"hello__"="hello %@";
```

On Windows, we can do this:

```
// In the Resources.resw file:
<data name="hello__" xml:space="preserve">
     <value>Hello {0}</value>
     <comment>{0} will be replace by user's name</comment>
</data>
```

Comment: try <!-- comment here -->

Comment: @quidproquo thanks for the comment! And it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For Android app, is there a way to add a comment message in the strings.xml for the translator?

Yes but it still needs to be a valid XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- my comment for the translators go here... -->
    <string name="string_name">text_string</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in some AndroidX libraries. 100% undocumented feature.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="string_name" description="my comment for the translators go here...">text_string</string>
</resources>
```